# Compile multiple Sass files to multiple destinations in VS Code

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code, sass

I am trying to compile Sass files in Visual Studio Code but I have two Sass files and I want them compiled inside two separate css files. I have **sass/global.scss** and **sass/media.scss** and I want them to compile into **css/global.css** and **css/media.css**

If I set the savePath to **/css** both files are compiling into **media.css**

How can I set **global.scss** to compile to **global.css** and **media.scss** compile to **media.css**

I am using the Live Sass Compiler extension.

Thank you.

Comment: I looked at the Live Sass Compiler repository - 230 issues - maintainer needs help.  I would investigate another way to get this done, like gulp or another task runner.

Comment: @Mark thank you. Perhaps I should explore Gulp or Webpack.